# Prolog average of a list

Tags: prolog

When I run the count and sum functions separately I get the right output, but when I run average it always returns false, why?

```
count([],X):- X is 0.
count([_|T],X):- count(T,Y), X is 1+Y.

sum([], 0).
sum([H|T], Sum):- sum(T,Rest), Sum is H+Rest.

average([],Y):- Y is 0.
average([_|X],Y):- sum(X,Sum), count(X,C), C >0, Y is Sum/C.
```

Comment: are you sure the answer _always_ is 'false'??? 
average([1,2],A). in my system (swi prolog 8.3.28, win8.1) returns A = 2. ;)

Comment: btw - your average definition does NOT support the case, when the first argument is one-element list - try to rewrite it as:
'average([_|X], Y):- writeln(X), sum(X,Sum), count(X, C), C > 0, Y is Sum/C.'
and you will see it...
so you have to deal with that case, too...

Comment: btw2: probably you'll find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447546/how-to-do-average-in-prolog) and [that article](http://www.storytotell.org/post/how-to-average-in-prolog/) useful...

Comment: consider renaming these to `list_count`, `list_sum` and `list_average`; see [this video on naming Prolog predicates from channel The Power of Prolog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uska9DgJEoo) to explain why. You're thinking very procedurally and that will lead you to miss Prolog's strengths.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler You can also watch too many YT videos about the power of prolog and start believing all of it.

Comment: @TA_intern It was only a day since I read an answer where you were boasting about how much you like to learn from people with more knowledge. The author of that youtube channel has a doctorate in constraint logic programming, a dozen peer-reviewed articles on logic programming, wrote a book on Prolog, and is co-author of Scryer Prolog. If your only response to the suggestion is an ad-hominem dismissal, do better. If the suggestion is bad, explain why. If you prefer other names, explain why.

Answer (score 1):

In computing the average (arithmetic mean) of a list, why do you traverse the list twice? You can do it more simply like this (tail-recursive):

```
average( Xs, Avg ) :- summarize(Xs,0,0,Sum,Cnt), Avg is Sum/Cnt.

summarize( []     , S  , C  , S , C ) .
summarize( [X|Xs] , S1 , C1 , S , C ) :-
  S2 is S1+X,
  C2 is C1+1,
  summarize(Xs,S2,C2,S,C).
```

Or (not tail-recursive):

```
average( Xs, Avg ) :- summarize(Xs,0,0,Sum,Cnt), Avg is Sum/Cnt.

summarize( []     , 0 , 0 ) .
summarize( [X|Xs] , S , C ) :-
  summarize(Xs, S1, C1 ),
  S is S1+X,
  C is C1+1
  .
```